# Youtube player ставит паузу после показа navagation drawer

Tags: java, android, youtube-android-api

В приложении использую com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer для видео с ютуба. Все работает отлично, только если во время воспроизведения видео открыть navigation drawer, то видео останавливается примерно через секунду. 
Как изменить такое поведение плеера?

если сделать так, то видео идет рывками по 1 секунде

```
@Override
public void onStopped() { 
  player.play();
}
```

Comment: никак. ютуб не терпит чего бы то ни было над плеером.

Comment: спасибо, я уже понял((